# Error while using PhantomJS in Selenium: NoSuchMethodError org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to run very simple Java automation test case using PhantomJS. I am using following version:

1. selenium-server-standalone3.8.1.jar
2. PhantomJS 2.1.1 version for Windows
3. PhantomJSdriver.jar 1.1. version

My code desired capabilities and driver launch is as follow:

```
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(
                PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                "C:/Program Files/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe"   //java web start / jnpl file...
                // "/Controller/phantomjs.exe"
        );

        //SET enabled javascript for php script on WEB page to transform it to picture:
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        String [] phantomJsArgs = {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"};
        caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomJsArgs);

        //CREATING WEB driver
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

However, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:178)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
>     at HD_PhantomJSTest1.main(HD_PhantomJSTest1.java:33) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.Proxies  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 3 more

Comment: How are you doing the build? It looks like some libraries are not found on the relative path. Make you sure you import all your dependencies or use Maven to take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`**

**`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`** is observed when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time.

As an example, if we have a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that class is not available during run-time then JVM will throw **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`**.

From your `Test Bed` information, I am not sure about the inclusion of **`PhantomJSdriver.jar 1.1. version`**. Current implementation of **`PhantomJS`** doesn't need any additional jar as such. Relevant **`Selenium JARs`** resolves the required dependencies. So you can remove the **`PhantomJSdriver.jar 1.1. version`**.

Other than that, I don't see any such error in your code. However after a bit of code formatting I executed your code with my configuration and was **`SUCCESS`** as follows:

```
@Test
public void verifyFacebookTitle()
{
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
    ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    String [] phantomJsArgs = {"--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"};
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomJsArgs);
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

Output on my console :

```
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Facebook – log in or sign up
[INFO  - 2017-12-06T08:24:22.972Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
PASSED: verifyFacebookTitle

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```